# How should I avoid orphan and widow lines in Context

Tags: context, widows-orphans

Typesetting a very simple document (no maths etc, just text, quotations and images), I am stuck with several orphan and widow lines. Is there a way to make Context avoid doing this? I can't find any mention of it on the Context Wiki or on this site.

Sorry for such a basic question!

Comment: Can you post an example?

Comment: Put \vfil between every paragraph ;-)

Comment: Have you tried `\widowpenalty10000` and `\clubpenalty10000`?

Comment: @Aditya Not very easily -- these are very long documents I'm talking about and I can't really reproduce these occurences which seem to be pretty random. I'm using something pretty close to pandoc's default template to spit out the context from markdown.

Comment: @DaveSmith: Normally, ConTeXt tries hard not to create orphans and widows, so it is hard to suggest solutions without seeing the problem. You can try `\setuptolerance[vertical,verytolerant]`.